# Android - read permission denied on /sdcard

Tags: android, file-permissions

Using the **termux** (https://termux.com) terminal-emulation program, I type the following command:

```
ls /sdcard
```

I get the following error:

```
ls: can't open '/sdcard': Permission denied
```

No, my device is not rooted, nor do I plan to root it - so I can not give any information that I'd have to root the device to obtain. However, not being rooted never in the past prevented me from having read access to the /sdcard directory - so this is new (and disturbing).

Granted - it's been a few months since previously I tried to do this - but this new limitation from Android seriously hampers the usability of **termux** and who-knows-what-else -- as I need to be able to have access to files that are on my SD Card. (I can still do a lot, even if not everything, even without write permissions -- but am pretty much stuck in the water if I can't get read permissions, as is presently the case.)

Comment: First, Android has not had an `/sdcard` directory in years, other than perhaps as a symlink. Try using your device's actual external storage location. Second, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. Please use https://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to android.stackexchange.com - I will move my question there. However - for what it's worth, I did also identify the location of the symlink and try the 'ls' command there - and got the same result.

Comment: But thanks for referring me to the other stackexchange thing -- I just finished putting an improved version of my question there: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/154646/no-permissions-for-termux-to-access-sd-card-even-for-reading

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue, easly solved by typing termux-setup-storage. This will open the window to obtain storage r/w permissions and the job is done.
Be sure to run previously apt update and apt upgrade to have it available.